# What does the phrase "trades" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the word **trades** in the following (made-up) sentence:

> In the game you will find that *Blades* trades open worlds for quests
>   through scary dungeons.

The sentence is from a description of the game "The Elder Scrolls: Blades". Here is a reference text (it does not contain the sentence above) from Wikipedia:

> The Elder Scrolls: Blades is an action role-playing game played from a
>   first-person perspective.[1] The game was designed specifically for
>   mobile devices and features nearly-unavoidable one-on-one combat,
>   which is engaged by tapping, swiping, or using virtual dual-stick
>   controls via touch screen.[1][2][3] Unlike the majority of the
>   installments in the series, which are primarily built on open-world
>   and world map features, the game's overall design is linear, due to
>   the challenges and limitations of mobile devices.[4] Another
>   distinction is that the abilities of sneaking around non-playable
>   characters, moving corpses, and hiding/storing/stealing items were not
>   included in the game. Combat includes using melee weapons, magic
>   spells, and ranged attacks.[1] Regarding the use of magic, the player
>   can only equip up to three different magic spells to use during
>   combat. The game features dungeons that are both hand-crafted by
>   designers and procedurally generated.[1] Players can customize and
>   level up their characters to enhance their abilities.[1][2]
>
> Blades features three main game modes: Abyss, Arena, and Town. Abyss
>   offers a roguelike experience in which the player must attempt to get
>   as far as possible in an endless dungeon. Despite not connected to the
>   game's story, the endless dungeon is ideal to gain experience and
>   strength for the player. Arena is a player versus player multiplayer
>   mode in which two players battle against each other.[3] Town is the
>   game's main mode, which is a hub area where the player can receive
>   quests and meet non-player characters (NPCs), in order to progress the
>   story.[3][2] The player's hub town initially starts destroyed and they
>   are tasked with rebuilding and upgrading it, which consequently
>   unlocks more quests and NPCs.[3] Players can visit their friends' hub
>   towns.[2][5]

I am confused by the word "trades". Does it mean "in-game purchases" here? Or does the phrase "trades open" have an idiomatic connotation that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, 'trades' could be replaced with 'exchanges' or possibly 'replaces'

In other words, the piece is saying that Blades has 'scary dungeons' *rather than* 'open worlds'.

Like many English words, 'trades' has several different meaning according to context.